# Not getting help when asked for

Tags: software-industry, management, manager, developer, junior

I am working in a large IT company. My position is a firmware developer, I have ~4 years of experience of writing firmware and electronics engineering combined. The company sees me as a junior, not far from middle level developer.

There are several bad things about the workflow of the development teams, however please do no get sidetracked. The developers are divided into groups of six or similar teams, each team has a lead which is an experienced developer. There is a lot of legacy code to be maintained, which my most work consists of, however the company is not creating any documentation of the firmware. Therefore the only way to understand what code does is just to read it through or to debug it. It is real time embedded OS, therefore it's merely possible to use debugger, the only real option is use print statements.

Analyzing the code would not be a problem if I was able to get when needed. Sometimes I reach a dead end for myself, where I do not have any ideas what to do next. I try to come up with ideas what can be done, however time passes by and without any progress for hours. Occasionally I ask some people for help without involvement of my group lead. There are times when the only one that can help my is the same senior developer who wrote that piece of code. Most of the times these few people (there are like 4 of them) who wrote the whole platform are busy or just ignores men. At this point there is no choice but ask for a team manager intervention, since I value my on and company's time, and money. Moreover, there are deadlines which needs to be met.

On rare occasions I contact my manager for help inquiry explaining that only one guy can help me to solve the problem, since only he has worked with that piece of code. In addition to this, I do explain what was done from my side, what was tried, observations and conclusions. Moreover, sometimes I need just few questions to be answered which I do explain to the manager. If he decides not to help, whichever the reason for it, he says: "You should do this on your own". After this, he does not contact the senior developer, leaving me alone with the problem and without any suggestions.

Once in a while this goes to the extreme, where the deadline is tomorrow/today because of mine or other employees' fault. Most of the time the manager declines to contact the senior to help me saying "You should solve the bug on your onw".

I was told on several reviews I am not enough independent employee for asking help from others.

My questions: is this a normal behavior towards me? Is this a problem with me because sometimes I need a hand? How do I deal with this? This is driving me crazy, since I am being blamed for times of low productivity and for asking help. I feel like should quit this company in a half of year or so if I am not able to avoid these type of situations.

Thank you for your time reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real time firmware debugging is a serious challenge. You have not just the issues with "does the code work" but also the issues of "does it work in the allotted time?" It takes significant imagination to read existing code and determine what types of problems could be happening with that code and associated interrupts and possible multi-tasking overlaying your memory space.

What you describe as your issues show that you don't have the skills to dig in and find out what is happening with existing code or to imagine what might be happening. In my mind, that does put you as a junior person *in* *this* *position*. Yes, you might be considered a "journeyman" in another position, but not this one.

So, the real question is: "How to ask the senior people for ideas of how to proceed?"

In any diagnostic situation, I ask first what are the expected results and then, what are the observed results. The next question is, "what kind of inputs could cause those observed results?" This is where the imagination comes in. Go through the code and identify all the inputs that could be coming in including interrupts. Sometimes, you can pull the code out of the real time environment and see how it operates in a regular environment. (This is where the print statements help.)

So, to ask senior people for help, ask first how to find out what the expected results should be.